# Thread with infinite Loop stops after catching some Exception

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, exception, thread-sleep

I have written following code. i want when control becomes 1 the infinite loop should stop. Otherwise it keeps on updating the SQL database after regular period of time. Some kind of exception is causing it to the thread to terminate. I am not able to figure it out. Can anybody help with it.

```
     public void run()
     {

    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("I am working t asfbjakhbfjabf");
        synchronized(lock)
        {
            if(control==1)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(wTIME);
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
            String st="SELECT count FROM ThreadResults WHERE ThreadNo = "
                                        +t;
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute(st);
            ResultSet resultSet = stmt.getResultSet();
            boolean b=resultSet.next();
            synchronized(WebCrawler.seed.lock6)
            {
                 float t1=(System.currentTimeMillis()-time)/60000;
                 if(b)
                 {
                    String s2="UPDATE ThreadResults SET count = "+WebCrawler.seed.count+",                      time = "+t1+" WHERE ThreadNo = "+t;
                   System.out.println("updated count");
                   stmt.executeUpdate(s2);
                  }
                 else
                 {
                   String s1="INSERT ThreadResults VALUES("+t+" ,"+WebCrawler.seed.count+" ,"+t1+")";
                    System.out.println("inserting count");
                    stmt.executeUpdate(s1);
                  }
            }
            resultSet.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException c)
        {
           System.out.println("caught in thread resilt updation "+ c.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not a preferred way to schedule a repeated task, you can fix it by catching `Throwable` instead of your explicit list of exceptions. That way you will make sure you catch anything that can theoretically be thrown. Be sure to print the whole exception stacktrace, not just the message.

When you fix the catching, you will need to additionally fix the cleanup logic: put the `close` statements into a `finally`. Better yet, rewrite your code to use Automatic Resource Management. The syntax is `try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) { ... }`.

The proper way to schedule a repeated task is by using the Executors:

```
final ScheduledExecutorService sched = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
sched.scheduleWithFixedDelay(task, 0, wTIME, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: I tried to use Throwable but still after executing some time. the Thread stops updation of Database. Can some another thread can cause it to terminate??

Comment: You should insert a print statement at the start of the task to see if it gets executed at all. Another possibility is that it blocks. I see you have a `synchronized` in there, that could be one source. Another is blocking of the database call.

Comment: yes. it is working fine. For first upto 15 to 24 times it is been executed. Moreocer I am not seeing any error message being printed by catch exception of this thread and the thread suddenly stops.

Comment: I have getting this message may be due to some another thread                org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryExecute INFO: Retrying request . Can this cause the termination of thread

Comment: The thread cannot possibly terminate without an exception. If you catch `Throwable`, you'll see the exception. The only other option is that it doesn't in fact terminate, but block.

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
catch(Exception e)
```

instead of what you wrote. It will catch all exceptions.